# How to output serialized JSON view data as an array of objects, instead of wrapped in an outer object?

Tags: arrays, json, cakephp, serialization, format

I am converting the returning value of CakePHP array to JSON, currently its like this:

```
{
  "platformusers" : [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "user1"
    },
    {
      "id" : "3",
      "name" : "user3"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
[
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "name" : "user1"
    },
    {
      "id" : "3",
      "name" : "user3"
    }
]
```

I am trying with *<del>Set::extract('{n}.Model', $data)</del>* Hash::extract('{n}.Model', $data) with no luck at all.

Full code:

```
    $platformusers = $this->Platformuser->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Platformuser.id', 'Platformuser.name')
    ));

    $platformusers = Hash::extract('{n}.Platformuser', $platformusers);

    $this->set(array(
        'platformusers' => $platformusers,
        '_serialize' => array('platformusers')
    ));
```

Comment: Set is deprecated, use `Hash::extract($platformusers, '{n}.Platformuser');` instead.

Comment: Thanks! :), was reading old documentation.

Comment: I guess it's just a copy/paste error but Hash syntax is different from Set syntax. So: `Hash::extract($data, '{n}.Model'}` . Data first and then path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set a `string` for the `_serialize` option instead of an `array`. An `array` indicates that there might be multiple view vars that need to be serialized, and that requires them to be packed into separate object properties.

```
$this->set(array(
    'platformusers' => $platformusers,
    '_serialize' => 'platformusers'
));
```

That should give you the desired result.