# CakePHP Json response without key

Tags: json, cakephp

I'm using cakephp to write a webservice. So to response a json result the I used to _serialize, but _serialize require an array with the key => value

```
 return array(
        'data' => $data,
        '_serialize' => array('data'));
```

And response in Restful client:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "appt1",
        "start": "2013-12-05 14:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "appt2",
        "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 17:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "appt3",
        "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#ff00ff",
        "allDay": false
    }
]
```

}

Question: how can I remove key 'data' in the result look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "appt1",
        "start": "2013-12-05 14:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "appt2",
        "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 17:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "appt3",
        "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
        "backgroundColor": "#ff00ff",
        "allDay": false
    }
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP array format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250477/cakephp-array-format)

Comment: use http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-JsonView.html link to get @ndm answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late here.. but anyway, here is what you were looking for:

```
$this->set([
    'data' => $data,
    '_serialize' => 'data',
]);
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember that JSON is just a string to PHP, so the literal answer to you question is that you could use `substr()` or `preg_match()` if you like. This is, of course, not the correct way to do things. The correct way to do this is:

1. Decode your REST data into an standard PHP object.
2. Assign the class variable `$data` to a new variable
3. Encode it back to JSON:

Voila:

```
$data = json_decode('{
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "appt1",
                "start": "2013-12-05 14:00:00",
                "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
                "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
                "allDay": false
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "appt2",
                "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
                "end": "2013-12-05 17:00:00",
                "backgroundColor": "#00ff00",
                "allDay": false
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "title": "appt3",
                "start": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
                "end": "2013-12-05 15:00:00",
                "backgroundColor": "#ff00ff",
                "allDay": false
            }
        ]
        }');
        $data = json_encode($data['data']);
);
```

Comment: To whomever chose to down vote this without even explaining yourself, *run* this code, it produces, verbatim, the result the Viet HP asked for. If you're going to downvote a functioning answer, at least have the courtesy to explain yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it was kinda obvious - check the duplicate question. The snippet itself might work, but it's not applicable in the OPs situation, he's using CakePHP and lets the [**JSON view**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) generate the JSON data automatically.