# Remove model name from json array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I've set up a custom search action in my cakephp controller

```
public function search() {

$results = [];
$results['data'] = $this->Content->find('first', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array($this->request->params['pass'][0] . ' like' => "%" . $this->request->params['pass'][1] . "%")), array('contain' => false)
    );

if(count($results['data'])>0){
    $results['success'] = true;
    $this->set(compact('results'));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('results'));
}
else{
    $results['success'] = false;

}

}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the rest of my API formats data like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
{
    "id": "5509be6c-9ef8-42c3-af39-2d492773a233",
    "title": "test2",
    },
    {
        "id": "5509be6c-9ef8-42c3-af39-2d492773a233",
        "title": "test1"
    }
    ]
}
```

but what I'm getting from cakephp right now for my search action is this:

```
{
"results": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "Content": {
            "id": "52efcbeb-e984-4a2e-b76f-0cc34056922c",
            "title": "Homeasdfasdf",
        }
    }
}}
```

How do I get rid of the extra "results" array wrapper so that my data is coming out in the same format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP array format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250477/cakephp-array-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.current.php) php function. In your controller make

```
$results = current($results);
```

before the `set()` call