# Remove resource wrapper from CakePHP REST API JSON

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251077/135101). I understand the answer given there. The OP of that question doesn't seem to have my issue.

I am using CakePHP 2.2.3. I am fetching a resource like this:

```
http://cakephpsite/lead_posts.json
```

and it returns results like this:

```
[
    {
        "LeadPost": {
            "id": "1",
            "fieldA": "blah",
            "fieldB": "blah2",
        }
    {
        "LeadPost": {
            "id": "1",
            "fieldA": "blah",
            "fieldB": "blah2"
        }
    }
]
```

**See the `LeadPost` wrapper on each object? I'm not sure why it's there. I want to remove it.**

The LeadPost model extends AppModel and is otherwise empty.

LeadPostsController.php

```
class LeadPostsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $records = $this->LeadPost->find('all', ['limit' => 20]);
        $this->set(array(
            'leadposts' => $records,
            '_serialize' => 'leadposts'
        ));
    }
}
```

My routing is very simple:

```
Router::mapResources('lead_posts');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Hash utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) to rewrite the results returned before setting the data for the View:-

```
class LeadPostsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $records = $this->LeadPost->find('all', ['limit' => 20]);
        $this->set(array(
            'leadposts' => Hash::extract($records, '{n}.LeadPost'),
            '_serialize' => 'leadposts'
        ));
    }
}
```

Here `Hash::extract($records, '{n}.LeadPost')` will rewrite your array so that the `LeadPost` index is removed. It won't maintain the original array indexes, but unless you've messed with them in an `afterFind` callback should be the same.

You could do this in the Model's `afterFind` as burzum suggests, but it feels more natural to me to do this in the Controller as we are specifically preparing the data for the View.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why the records are wrapped in the first place would you? It seems non-standard, and I can't find any CakePHP documentation about the fact.

Comment: @TylerCollier Cake's `find` method always (excluding `find('list')`) indexes by alias to distinguish which model data belongs to. If you use the containable behavior to get associated models in the same `find` you will see the data from each table appropriately indexed by alias. You can do a lot to manipulate the results returned using the powerful Hash utility to get data in a format more appropriate to your needs. Hope that answers your question. Not sure I've explained it that well.

Comment: Examples of this in action from the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone

Comment: I find those docs unclear on this issue. There, they keep showing different types of records, e.g. User and Profile. I got rid of the outter wrappers by not using an array with `_serialize`. It seems pretty silly, then, that if you used an array with `_serialize`, you'd have a wrapper on the array and on each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use the afterFind() model callback to reformat the standard data structure. But this will be reformatted for other calls as well then.
2. [Or use JSON views](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#creating-json-views).

Two will be basically the same as one except that you move the logic in the view file. The 2nd option is the better one because of this.

Comment: I prefer drmonkeyninja's answer because, as he mentions, in the controller seems like the right place to do this. I don't like the idea of doing it in the view because I don't want to do it in each view, so in code seems like the DRY way.