# Cannot get JSON Feed to work in Full Calendar with CakePHP 3.x

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, fullcalendar, cakephp-3.x

I am using CakePHP 3.1 and I can get the events to show on the calendar if they are hard coded. I can also get the events by pasting the array into jsbin and then using the url to get the js file from jsbin as explained in the full calendar docs [here](http://fullcalendar.io/support/) and then using the [JSON Feed Template](http://fullcalendar.io/playground/jsbin.php?demo=json) link for standard FullCalendar. I need to be able to use the feed url to grab the events so that the events are dynamically added.

You can see my json feed array [here](https://www.utahreia.org/events/feed).
You can see the displayed object in console [here](https://www.utahreia.org/full-calendar).

Feed Method in controller:

```
public function feed($id=null) {
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
    $vars = $this->request->query([]);
    $conditions = ['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']];
    $events = $this->Events->find('all', $conditions)->contain(['EventTypes']);
    foreach($events as $event) {
        if($event->all_day === 1) {
            $allday = true;
            $end = $event->start;
        } else {
            $allday = false;
            $end = $event->end;
        }
        $json[] = array(
                'id' => $event->id,
                'title'=> $event->title,
                'start'=> $event->start,
                'end' => $end,
                'allDay' => $allday,
                'url' => Router::url(['action' => 'view', $event->id]),
                'details' => $event->details,
                'className' => $event->event_type->color
        );
    }
    $this->set('json', json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['json']);
}
```

Rendering Full Calendar from ready.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today agendaDay,agendaWeek,month prev,next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        scrollTime: "08:00:00",
        aspectRatio: 2,
        editable: adminEdit,
        events: {
            url: 'https://www.utahreia.org/events/feed', //navigate to this url to see json feed array
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.qtip({
                content: event.details,
                position: { 
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        x: 10,
                        y: -5
                    }
                },
                style: {
                    name: 'light',
                    tip: 'leftTop'
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: just send the data array without creating outer object `{json: /* your data array*/}`

Comment: @charlietfl I would, but I am not sure how to do that. I believe CakePHP 3 is automatically creating the outer object.

Comment: no...you are when you set it inside `json` property. Just send the json_encode

Comment: @charlietfl you mean when I json_encode it? I am not sure where I am setting it inside json property.

Comment: you have 2 `set` and are nesting the data and serializing it as well. Just send the array

Comment: @charlietfl if you are referring to this line of code: $this->set('json', json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG)); This is how you set the variable for a view in CakePHP, which is why if you navigate to my feed url you can see the array. If I just set the json array like this: $this->set('json', $json); It still won't display the events.

Comment: I don't know CAKE ... I'm just telling you the structure being sent is wrong. why do you need to use a view to echo an array in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99732/discussion-between-battousai-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to specify the feed url or add a function for events

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

```
...
events: 'https://www.utahreia.org/events/feed',
...
```

or

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

```
...
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax();
}
...
```

Pasting the contents of your events feed into jsbin and calling it to get around the access countrol allowed origins, it works: [example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fecapeduke/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I mentioned above that I can get it to work by pasting the feed array into jsbin and calling the url like your last example. I have tried just using the feed url like your first example to no avail (I believe because of what charlietfl mentioned with the feed being wrapped in an outer object when it is requested). I will try your second example with the events function, but I doubt this will work.

Comment: In the success function of the ajax, in my head you would probably want to do: function(response){ callback(response.json); }    But that would need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); in my app controller was causing the problem. I removed that from my app controller and it now displays the events.

If you want to use the Request Handler and only have one item to serialize, you can do as @ndm suggested and use:

```
$this->set('_serialize', 'your_variable');
```

If you try and pass an array through serialize it will wrap your json and not work with FullCalendar:

```
$this->set('_serialize', ['your_variable']);
```

Comment: If that fixed it, then @charlietfl was right, your app sent the data in a wrong format, which is because you did not define the `_serialize` variable correctly, and because you JSON encoded the data manually! When passing an array for `_serialize`, the vars are being [**set as object properties**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250477/cakephp-array-format/19251077#19251077). Also the [**JSON view**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) will encode the data, hence you'll end up with double encoding.

Comment: @ndm so if I kept $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); in my app controller how would I change the code to not serialize twice? I have tried it without $this->set('_serialize', ['json']); and it still serialized twice. I have also tried it with only encoding the json variable in the feed view and still no luck.

Comment: Simply do not use `json_encode()`, do not use a template but a pure [**data view**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key), and pass a string to `_serialize` as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: @ndm do you know how the structure of this string should be? Just comma delimited?

Comment: @ndm I have tried creating a string a bunch of different ways and it still wraps my events in the {"json": ... }.

Comment: Why would you comma delimit anything, you only have a single view variable according to your code? So just pass its name as a string as shown, `set('_serialize', 'json')`.

Comment: @ndm wtf... I could have sworn I did that like 20 different times and it wasn't working, but for some reason it is now. Anyways thank you! It works with the request handler now. I think when I navigated to my feed url and it just said array it threw me off. If I navigated to my events/feed.json it shows the json correctly.