# jQuery autocomplete data returned but not displayed

Tags: php, jquery, css, cakephp-3.0, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get data from my SQL tables using Jquery auto complete and when I search the data is being returned correctly but it's not being displayed graphically with a drop down box.

my search.ctp

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'text']); ?>

<script>
jQuery('#id').autocomplete({
    source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Invoices', 'action' => 'search')); ?>'
});
</script>
```

my search function

```
public function search()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
    {
        $name = $this->request->query['term'];
        $resultArr = $this
            ->Invoices
            ->find()
            ->where(
                ['Invoices.id LIKE' => ($name . '%')],
                ['Invoices.id' => 'string']
            );

        $resultsArr = [];
        foreach ($resultArr as $result)  {
            $resultsArr[] = (strval($result['id']));
        }

        $this->set('invoices', $resultsArr);
        // This line is what handles converting your array into json
        // To get this to work you must load the request handler
        $this->set('_serialize', ['invoices']);
    }
}
```

as you can see it is returning data but no drop down.

[image]

Comment: Looks like its also returning a whole lot of "something not json" which is breaking the json parse on the receiving end most likely.

Comment: @Randall woops my bad forgot to remove some code I edited it if that's an better.

Comment: That is odd, as the basic behavior of .autocomplete is to just tack a div under the selected field. Its clearly hitting the server when you type something, and the server is returning a json array of items. So... my only guess can be, do you have some css that may be conflicting with the display of the choices?

Comment: Also, is it a new version of jquery ui.autocomplete? I ask because older versions just looked for newlines, not json arrays.

Comment: @Randall It is using jquery 1.10.2 i believe

Comment: do the js console say something?

Comment: Look at your JSON output, I'm pretty sure the autocomplete widget doesn't support objects with the data nested in an arbitrary property.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding `json_encode($resultsArr);` before serializing the data in my search function.

Comment: You just need to pass a string for the `_serialize` option **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250477/how-to-output-serialized-json-view-data-as-an-array-of-objects-instead-of-wrapp/19251077#19251077**.